# Flask + Nginx + Gunicorn VPS Ubuntu 12.04 Домен без порта

Tags: python, flask, supervisord

Здравствуйте.
Почти развернул Flask приложение на VPS Ubuntu 12.04.
Никогда до сих пор не использовал supervisor и fabric, по этому столкнулся с трудностями, которые не получается решить самостоятельно, не прибегая к помощи.

Если я меняю указанный ниже в gunicorn.conf `bind = '127.0.0.1:5000'` на `bind = 'illumiart.by:5000'`, то полуаю доступ к статике и странице с ошибкой https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mdxa.png 404, но по урлу illumiart.by:5000/static/asdas.pnf
Если же я не указываю порт, а пишу просто `bind = 'illumiart.by'`, то доступен, но уже на порту 8000.

Не получается получать содержимое illumiart.by, без указания порта.

Не понимаю как быть, вроде ведь не выдаёт никаких ошибок. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста. Возможно кто-то решал аналогичную задачу.

Всем заранее спасибо!

Использую fabfile:

```
# coding: utf-8
from fabric.api import run, env, cd, prefix, shell_env, local
from config import load_config

config = load_config()
host_string = config.HOST_STRING


def deploy():
    env.host_string = config.HOST_STRING
    with cd('/var/www/html/luminate'):
        with shell_env(MODE='PRODUCTION'):
            run('git reset --hard HEAD')
            run('git pull')
            run('npm install')
            run('gulp')
            with prefix('source venv/bin/activate'):
                run('pip install -r requirements.txt')
                #run('python manage.py db upgrade')
                run('python manage.py build')
            run('supervisorctl restart app')


def restart():
    env.host_string = config.HOST_STRING
run('supervisorctl restart app')
```

nginx.conf :

```
#:Website
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.illumiart.by;
    root /var/www/html/luminate;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_redirect   off;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        root /var/www/html/luminate/output;
        expires 15d;
    }

    location /pkg {
        root /var/www/html/luminate/output;
        expires 15d;
    }

    location /pages {
        root /var/www/html/luminate/output;
        expires 15d;
    }

    location /uploads {
        root /var/www/html/luminate;
        expires 15d;
    }
}

# 301 redirect
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  illumiart.by;
    return       301 http://www.illumiart.by$request_uri;
}
```

supervisor.conf :

```
[program:app]
command=/var/www/html/luminate/venv/bin/gunicorn -c deploy/gunicorn.conf wsgi:app
directory=/var/www/html/luminate
user=root
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment = MODE="PRODUCTION"
```

gunicorn.conf:

```
workers = 2
bind = '127.0.0.1:5000'
proc_name = 'app'
pidfile = '/tmp/app.pid'
```

[image: Скрин]

(Прошу прощения за скрин, работаю на VPS через TigerVNC Viewer, а как выделить текст и получить его в буфер обмена - ещё не разобрался)

Comment: У вас proxy_pass ведёт на порт 5000, а gunicorn запущен на 8888, советую определиться

Comment: @andreymal, выставил всё на 5000, результатов не принесло. 
Мне кажется, что я не правильно переносёс домен.